# implement update in save

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
    $ahorroga           = Ahorroga::findOrFail($id);
    $ahorroga->junta_id = $request->junta_id;
    $ahorroga->socio_id = $request->socio_id;
    $ahorroga->ahorro   = $request->ahorro;
    $ahorroga->estado   = $request->estado;

    if ($ahorroga->isDirty()) {
        $ahorroga->save();
        toast('Ahorro Garantia Editado', 'success');
        return redirect('ahorroga');
    }
    toast('No se detectaron cambios', 'error');
    return redirect('ahorroga');
```

I know I can use and save lines of code, But how to apply the **isDirty**

```
    Ahorroga::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it correct, then if you want to detect whether you updated stuff updated the table or not then below is the solution.
The best solution for this is to use `update()`, it returns true or false and  based on this you can do your further logic. For ex:

```
    $ahorroga           = Ahorroga::find($id);
    $ahorroga->junta_id = $request->junta_id;
    $ahorroga->socio_id = $request->socio_id;
    $ahorroga->ahorro   = $request->ahorro;
    $ahorroga->estado   = $request->estado;
    $id_updated = $ahorroga->update();
    if($id_updated )  {
     //if ture
    }else{
     //false
    }
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$id_updated' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: I missed semicolon before upadate() line of code. Updated it,please check it.

Comment: if this worked out then please upvote it. so that others who found this issue also able to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update($id)
{

$ahorroga->fill($request->only([
    'junta_id', 'socio_id', 'ahorro','estado',
]);

if(!$ahorroga->isDirty()) {
    toast('No se detectaron cambios', 'error');
    return back();
}

$ahorroga->save();
toast('Ahorro Garantia Editado', 'success');

return redirect()->route();

}
```

In place of using `isDirty()`, you can also use `isClean()`

```
if($ahorroga->isClean()) {
    // some error handling here
}
```

`isDirty` means there was changes. `isClean` means there was no change.